# I dont understand why my list only shows the last person registered and not all of them?

Tags: c, if-statement, malloc, function-definition

I had to make a list in which i added the name, job and work experience of some added people, but after i register 3+ people, if i click "Afisare" (Show), it only shows the last input. Where's the issue?
I thought it had to do with my add(adaugare) function, but im not sure.
Hi! I had to make a list in which i added the name, job and work experience of some added people, but after i register 3+ people, if i click "Afisare" (Show), it only shows the last input. Where's the issue?
I thought it had to do with my add(adaugare) function, but im not sure.(sorry for the repetition, the character limit is high =] )

```
typedef struct corporatisti
{
    char nume[20];
    char* functie;
    int vechime;
    struct corporatisti* urm;

}C;
///numele sa aibe minim 4 vocale
int validare(char*s)
{
    int i,k=0,ok=0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (*(s + i) =='a' || *(s + i) == 'e' || *(s + i) == 'i' || *(s + i) == 'o' || *(s + i) == 'u')
        {
            k++;
        }
        if (k == 4)
        {
            ok = 1;
            break;
            
        }

    }
    return ok;

}

C* adaugare(C*prim)
{
    
    char aux_nume[20], functie_aux[20];
    C*p;

    do
    {
        printf("nume:");
        scanf(" %s", aux_nume);

    } while (!validare(aux_nume));
    printf("functie:");
    scanf(" %s", functie_aux);
    p = (C*)malloc(sizeof(C));
    p->functie = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(functie_aux) + 1));
    strcpy(p->nume, aux_nume);
    strcpy(p->functie, functie_aux);
    p->vechime = strlen(p->functie);
    p->urm = NULL;

    if (prim = NULL)
        return p;
    else 
    { p->urm = prim; 
    return p;
    }

}

void afisare(C*prim)
{
    C*p;
    for (p = prim; p != NULL; p = p->urm)
    {
        printf("%s ", p->nume);
        printf("%s ", p->functie);
        printf("%d", p->vechime);
        printf("\n");

    }

}
int main()
{
    C*prim,*q;
    prim = NULL;
    int opt;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Alegeti:\n");//means choose option
        printf("0.Iesire\n");
        printf("1.Adauga\n");
        printf("2.Scrie\n");
        printf("Opt este:");
        scanf("%d", &opt);

        switch (opt)
        {
        case 0:exit(0);
        case 1:prim=adaugare(prim);//means add
            break;
        case 2:afisare(prim);//means show
            break;
        default:printf("Opt inexistenta!");
            break;
        }



    }
```

Comment: for  start you dont mean this `(char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(functie_aux) + 1));` that will allocate 5 bytes - the sizeof an int +1, you just want `malloc(strlen(..) + `)`. Or better use strdup

Comment: @cat_mat_novice You are using  the assignment operator if (prim = NULL) instead of the comparison operator ==.

Comment: makes sense, i was skeptical about it too, but i modified it now. thank u!

Comment: you're right...embarassing =) thank you! i have been at it for hours now!

Comment: @pm100 Close.  `sizeof(strlen(functie_aux) + 1)` is the size of the type of the sum  of an `size_t + int`, which is likely `sizeof(size_t)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - yup - i misread where the parens were

Answer (score 1):

At least these problems,

**Not having all compiler warnings enabled**

A good well enabled compiler would whine about `if (prim = NULL)`.  Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.

**Undersized allocation**

`sizeof(strlen(functie_aux) + 1)` is the size of a `size_t`, perhaps 4 or 8 bytes. [@pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75239847/i-dont-understand-why-my-list-only-shows-the-last-person-registered-and-not-all/75239997?noredirect=1#comment132769114_75239847)

Cast not needed.

```
// p->functie = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(functie_aux) + 1));
p->functie = malloc(strlen(functie_aux) + 1);
```

Good practice to check for success.

```
if (p->functie == NULL) {
  // TBD code to handle out of memory.
  fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
strcpy(p->functie, functie_aux);
```

**Incorrect compare**

`=` assigns.  `==` compares. [@Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75239847/i-dont-understand-why-my-list-only-shows-the-last-person-registered-and-not-all/75239997?noredirect=1#comment132769269_75239847)

```
// if (prim = NULL)
if (prim == NULL)
```

**Overflow risks**

`scanf(" %s", aux_nume);` risks attempting to save too much.
Use a *width* 1 less than the size.

Check return value.

Space not needed.

```
// scanf(" %s", aux_nume);
if (scanf("%19s", aux_nume) != 1) {
  // TBD code to handle bad input.
  fprintf(stderr, "No numeric input.\n");
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

**`strlen()` not needed**

No need to run down the string to find its length and then walk down again and maybe quit the loop early.  Instead look for the *null character*.

```
// for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
for (i = 0; s[i]; i++)
```

Comment: "assign instead of compare" is "bloat code"...No need for the conditional at all...

Comment: @Fe2O3 As advertised up front "At least these problems,".

Answer (score 0):

here is your bug

```
if (prim = NULL)
```

you mean

```
if (prim == NULL)
```

Comment: you're right...embarassing =) thank you! i have been at it for hours now!

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* .... */
    p->urm = NULL;

    if (prim = NULL) // wrong...
        return p;
    else 
    { p->urm = prim; 
    return p;
    }
```

The "assignment instead of equality" problem would not even have arisen if you'd thought a bit more about the logic...

All you need is:

```
    /* ... */
    p->urm = prim; // assigns NULL in the first instance.
    return p;
```

Comment: yes, i didn't notice the operator was missing, fixed it now!

Comment: There is NO need for the conditional `if/else`... Think about it...

Comment: it's a model i did in class and was trying to redo for an exam tommorow, i will probably start to modify it after my own taste when i'll be experienced enough, but right now id rather play with stuff that i know works for sure to get a good grade! i will consider your advice after the exam. thank you!

Comment: It's up to you. My hunch is you'd get a better grade if you think about this now and see that you've written unnecessary lines of code. In so doing, you've opened the door to a bug that you've "spent hours" not seeing... It's up to you...